# Enable CORS in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cross-domain, django-cors-headers

I am using `Django 1.11` and it seems that the python module `django-cors-headers` is till `Django 1.10`.

In the Django documentation, they mention to use this module or write custom middleware.
I did not find any information online about writing `cors middleware` for `Django 1.11` and the examples for previews versions did not work.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: i am using django cors headers with django 1.11.1 on python 3.6 without any issues. Can you try it out and check if you get any errors.

Comment: I am using pyton 3.4

Comment: that shouldn't matter you can use any version of python 3

Comment: I do the same with @zaphod100.10, without any issues until now

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: The response don\`t have the headers, added the middleware and a whitelist and added `corsheaders` to installed apps... no any errors in the backend only in the browser

Comment: @OzBar-Shalom Did u solve the issue?, I too face the same now

Comment: @zaphod100.10 what version of `django_cors_headers` are you using? I wanted to check what version is compatible with `django==1.11`

Answer (score 1):

django-cors-headers 3.2.1 should works with django 1.11 according to their documentation for 3.2.1 version.
https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/3.2.1/